# How Do I Check If An Element In An Array Is An Address?

Tags: c

### Problem

I have an `array` initialized using `malloc`. When that array is initialized, if I print out an element of that `array` without replacing any value, then it returns the value `-842150451` for me - which I assume will not always return the same value (I believe this is the address converted into an integer).

I want to be able to check if the index of an array is an address. If so, I want to be able to replace the value with an integer, or multiply it.

#### For example:

```
if(array[0] == address) Then
array[0] = 5; //Replaces the value of the address with a random integer.

else
array[0] *= 3; // Otherwise, if the element at index 0 is not an address, then multiply the number by an arbitrary integer.
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Not at all.

Comment: malloc does not initialize the allocated memory. All you get by accessing that memory is garbage. The `-842150451` you are seeing is some random value. What do you mean by address?

Comment: Is it possible for me to detect if it is garbage? Then change the value if it is garbage?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Garbage could be anything, including valid values.

Comment: It's a number. It's not dirty or something..

Comment: What makes you think it's returning an address? It's just returning whatever integer happens to be in the array element before you assign to it.

Comment: If some other part of the program allocated and then freed some memory, `malloc()` will often return that same memory, and when you access it you'll get whatever the earlier part stored in there.

Comment: what is the data type of `array`?

Comment: Maybe you should use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`. It initializes everything to `0`.

Comment: *"Is it possible for me to detect if it is garbage?"* - it ***is*** garbage until you write to it. Note that the content of memory is relevant *in its context*. To the processor it is all just numbers. If you allocate memory for an array of pointers, it contains addresses. if you allocate it for an array ont integers, it contains ... integers.

Comment: No, this is not an address, this is you, not initializing your arrays. Uninitialized arrays contain garbage until you initialize it with non-garbage values.

Comment: Every element of an array has its own address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to tell whether an array element has been initialized or not.

You could use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, this automatically initializes everything to `0`, so you could do:

```
if (array[0] == 0) {
    array[0] = 5;
} else {
    array[0] *= 3;
}
```

But this won't work if `0` is a valid value in your array.

Instead of an array of integers, you could use an array of structs, and put an `initialized` field in the struct.

```
struct element {
    int initialized;
    int value;
};
```

After allocating the array, you'll need to fill in the `initialized` field in all the elements, to show that the values aren't yet initialized.

```
array = malloc(N * sizeof(struct element));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    array[i].initialized = 0;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
if (!array[0].initialized) {
    array[0].value = 5;
    array[0].initialized = 1;
} else {
    array[0].value *= 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array initialized using malloc.

No, you have not. `malloc()` does not initialise the memory it returns the address to.

> I want to be able to replace the value with an integer, or multiply it. [...]
>   Is this possible to do?

No, as you may not read uninitialised memory, as the expression

```
(array[0] == address)
```

does. If the code does it provokes undefined behaviour.